# Aggs in Elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

a newbie here!

I was trying to use elastic4s to connect elasticsearch with scala. However, I do not find anything to calculate aggregations. Is it not yet supported? What other option do I have?

Comment: what about https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/aggregations.scala ?

Comment: You can also read http://elastic4s.readthedocs.org/en/stable/guide/search/#aggregations

Comment: Hey, thanks. Will check and get back!